# How to play or pause the mplayer using the play and pause buttons of Qt window?

Tags: qt

How to play or pause the mplayer using the play and pause buttons of Qt window, if I know the process id? Is there any command to stop and pause using PID?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to be multiplatform, in Linux you can use `SIGSTOP` to pause and `SIGCONT` to continue.

For example to stop process with PID 123:

```
kill -SIGSTOP 123
```

And then continue:

```
kill -SIGCONT 123
```

This is not directly portable to other platforms (majority of mobile phones, Windows).